# Magento 1 - Add store code to body as class on all pages

Tags: magento-1, template

I have a website with 2 stores, one for each language. Magento adds the store name to the body on CMS pages, but not on the rest of the sites. The only setting that is `remotely related` allows me to add the store code to the url, but this is not what I want.

I googled for an answer and I didn't find what I'm looking for.

**Has anyone done this before and found a solution?**

Comment: My free extension *MobWeb_CustomBodyClasses* allows you to customize the body classes: https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_CustomBodyClasses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by [`event/observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

As peras  magento system `body class`  has been set by `addBodyClass()` of `Mage_Page_Block_Html`,So on  event of `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` fire `an observer`  and on this observer using  `addBodyClass()` function class **Mage_Page_Block_Html**,you can add `store code  body tag`.

### config.xml code:

```
<events>
  <core_block_abstract_to_html_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>magento68574/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>AddClass</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler>
    </observers>
  </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
</events>
```

### Observer code:

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento68574_Model_Observer
{

            public function AddClass(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                 $block = $observer->getBlock();
            //echo get_class($block)."--->" .get_class( $block->getParentBlock())."<br/>";
                if (get_class($block) == 'Mage_Page_Block_Html') {

                    $block->addBodyClass(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());

                    }
            }

}
```

### Full Module:

**As per as your request, i have put full module**

**Step1:**  Observer path `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento68574/Model/Observer.php`

**code:**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento68574_Model_Observer
{

            public function AddClass(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                 $block = $observer->getBlock();
            //echo get_class($block)."--->" .get_class( $block->getParentBlock())."<br/>";
                if (get_class($block) == 'Mage_Page_Block_Html') {

                    $block->addBodyClass(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());

                    }
            }

}
```

**Step2:**  config  path `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento68574/etc/config.xml`

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento68574>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento68574>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento68574>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento68574_Model</class>
      </magento68574>
    </models>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_to_html_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento68574/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>AddClass</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </core_block_abstract_to_html_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Step3:** module file: `app/etc/modules/Stackexchange_Magento68574.xml`

**code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento68574>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento68574>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Amit. Which files should I use this code in? Please forgive my ignorance, I have very little experience with layout updated in magento.

Comment: Thanks again for your very complete answer. I have created the necessary files with the content you have provided in the specified folder structure, however no new class is added to the body. I have checked that the new extension shows up under System > Configuration > Advanced and that it's HTML output is enabled.

Comment: I have noticed that you use alternatively "Magento68574" and "Magento65569" in your code, is this correct?

Comment: edited.it was mistake...please ckd now

Comment: Thank you, I have marked your answer as correct since it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution is:

Go to

> app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/[yourlayout]/page/[mainlayout files].phtml 
>   [mainlayout files] = 2columns-left.phtml, 2columns-right.phtml, 1column.phtml and 3columns.phtml

Find the `<body>` tag and add:

```
echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()
```

The total bodyclass should look something like:

```
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass(). ' store-' .Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode().'"':'' ?>>
```

Above code outputs the following to the front-end:

```
<body class=" catalog-category-view categorypath category store-en">
```

The **store-en** is the class added for a store with storecode **'en'**. This wil be the storecode you entered in the backend under **system/Manage stores**

Comment: Thanks, by far the simplest answer and it works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this avoiding event/observer completely.

Add this in layout XML:

```
<default>
    <action method="addBodyClass" block="root">
         <store_code helper="YourNamespace_YourModule/getStoreCodeName" />
    </action>
</default>
```

And this helper method in `YourNamespace_YourModule` helper class:

```
public function getStoreCodeName()
{
  return Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
}
```