# Magento 1.9 - Overriding CSS files in Multi Site Environment

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am running Magento 1.9 in a multiple store environment. I am trying to have the exact same design for every store, **thus each store uses the same Theme**.

However, I need to make some slight changes in the CSS files for a specific store,but at the moment it is not possible because the CSS resources are being shared among each store.

To address this issue, I have **duplicated** the theme in the following path:

> ./app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme2
>
> ./skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme2

And then from **Admin>System>Design**, I have told Magento to use customtheme2 to that specific store.

Now I can easily change the CSS file for that store.

**My Question: Is this the correct (Standard) Approach to address my need?**

Comment: You can also create child theme

Answer (score 0):

My answer for your question is: Yes. 
Magento does not know your different styles on each store are slight or big. You should have a `default` theme on your package, then you dont need to duplicate whole theme and skin folder. 
Just need

- local.xml
- css
- images

Answer (score 0):

If you need very small change to specific store no need to create 2nd theme just add store id in body class and change css.

please check: [Add store code to body as class on all pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68574/add-store-code-to-body-as-class-on-all-pages) for detail

Answer (score 0):

app/

design/

frontend/

`Themename/`

`- default`

`- store_view (just overrides)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right way to do it, Magento allows you to set one design for each view **But**,  if it just to change `CSS` files, you can do it like this and this is fine, **however** if you also need to change templates, layouts, xml, images, etc... the best way to do it is to create a **child theme** which you specify the path in admin, this becomes more explicit useful and limits the errors.